# Rounding to the nearest integer power of a given base

Tags: algorithm, math, rounding

I'm trying to round a number to the next smallest power of another number. I'm not particular on which direction it rounds, but I prefer downwards if possible.

The number `x` that I'm rounding will satisfy: `x > 0`, and usually fits within the range `0 < x <= 1`. Only rarely will it be above 1.

More generally, my problem is: **Given a number `x`, how can I round it to the nearest integer power of some base `b`?**

I would like to be able to round towards arbitrary bases, but the ones I'm most concerned with at the moment is base 2 and fractional powers of 2 like 2^(1/2), 2^(1/4), and so forth. Here's my current algorithm for base 2.

```
double roundBaseTwo(double x)
{
    return 1.0 / (1 << (int)((log(x) * invlog2))
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got the right idea; for any base x, `x ^ floor( log_x(n) )` is what you want. (Where `log_x` represents 'log to the base *x*')
In C#:

```
static double roundBaseX(double num, double x)
{
    return Math.Pow(x, Math.Floor(Math.Log(num, x)));
}
```

If you can't take logarithms to an arbitrary base, just use the formula: `log_x(n) = log(n) / log(x)`

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for. Would you happen to know if there's any faster way of doing it, or am I stuck doing it this way? I was thinking of potentially doing a lookup table for common values, since this was something that would be computed extremely frequently in my main loop.

Comment: You're welcome. :) About speeding it up, a lookup table would do rather well, I think. If you can store all the powers of your base in an array (i.e. enough to cover the entire range you need), a simple binary search would be all you needed to do your rounding. Of course, you'd need one such array for every base you use.